# How to integrate $\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ { e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } } } dx$?

Tags: calculus

I tried using gamma function but there's no way I can change the limits as : $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Can you include some of your working as we then might be able to show you where you went wrong and help you, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One observation:

$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx=\sqrt{\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1e^{x^2+y^2}dx \ dy}\\
\le\sqrt{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^1 e^{r^2} r dr d\theta}=\sqrt{(e-1)\frac{\pi}{2}}\approx 1.64289$$

Otherwise, according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7De%5E%7Bx%5E2%7Ddx) you have $$\int_{0}^1e^{x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\mbox{erfi}(1)\approx 1.46265$$